# Lua referencing a HTML file

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

So I'm helping my friend with his server, and he wants a simple message of the day. I have made local html files for it

This is the directory
[image: desc]

This is the LUA code

[image: desc]

I tried to reference the local files but it doesn't show

Comment: It is spelled Lua not LUA.

Comment: please paste the code as script not an image.

Answer (score 1):

Use correct full path or setup local pathes correctly.
I mean this:

`/your/path/to/dir/Script/somefile.html`.
or , if you execute lua file inside the parent of `Script` folder use this:

`./Script/somefile.html`.

Imo, first choice is better .
For the future:
Please, use text instead of png-files.